# Get Point by Distance on Normal of a Equilateral Triangle going through middle Point

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

Given 3 arbitrary points *p1*,*p2* and *p3* in 3D-space which form a
equilateral triangle plane, how do I get a point *p4* by distance *d* on the Normal of that triangle plane which goes through the middle-point of that triangle.
I provided a image below so you better understand what i mean.
[image]

Comment: @PM2Ring the triangle is a equilateral triangle, I specefied the question, it should be more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an equilateral triangle, calculate the center of mass:
$$\vec c=\frac13(\vec p_1+\vec p_2+\vec p_3)$$
The direction of the normal can be found from the cross product of two vectors in the plane:
$$\vec n=(\vec p_1-\vec p_2)\times(\vec p_1-\vec p_3)$$
Then $$\vec p_4=d\frac{\vec n}{|\vec n|}+\vec c$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @purple: I forgot to add $\vec c$ to the last line. I've edited my answer